# min-content in css and content div

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I do "height div #grand_parent: min-content" but in execute height=0 .

```css
#grand_parent{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:min-content;
    background-color:red;
}
#parent{
    position: relative;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    float: right;
    width:70%;
    min-height: min-content;
}
.filse{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sifo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="grand_parent">
            <div id="parent">
                <div class="filse">
                    a
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can you say that it executes 0, Did you check it using javascript?

Comment: you need to clear float

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks

Comment: @MdTahazzot I didn't know the correct term. So I used exucute

Comment: I also think so, clear the float